# Launching QGIS from the command-line

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, command-line

When I run `qgis` (version 2.14) from the command line in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` (detailed error messages included below). However QGIS opens and runs perfectly when I launch it from the Applications launcher. QGIS has been installed using the standard Ubuntu repositories. I have tested the suggestions outlined [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186026/qgis-segmentation-fault-core-dumped), but they have not resolved the issue.

Error Messages output to terminal:

```py
Warning: loading of qgis translation failed [/usr/share/qgis/i18n//qgis_en_IE]
Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_IE]
Warning: QCss::Parser - Failed to load file  "/style.qss" 
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: No such file or directory
Warning: QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: /home/dmci/.qgis2//project_templates
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What is the solution if it is caused by the following issues:

```py
Warning: QCss::Parser - Failed to load file  "/style.qss" 
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I get these messages in 2.18/Trusty Ubuntu (and i'm sure some earlier versions too) but they seem to pass without incident. Have you tried running it in gdb to see where the error originates? (For me that's `gdb /usr/bin/qgis.bin`) and use the `bt` command when it segfaults.  It can sometimes give clues.

Comment: Same here with QGIS 2.14.9 on Ubuntu 14.04, but QGIS runs normal afterwards. The `Segmentation fault` must have a different reason.

Comment: If I try `ipdb` I get the following: `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /usr/bin/qgis.bin on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging`

Comment: try qgis --noplugins to see if it comes from the plugins. Also check the line from the qgis.desktop file to see what it actually does when you launch it through the app launcher: cat /usr/share/applications/qgis.desktop | grep Exec.

Comment: The output from `qgis.desktop` is `TryExec=/usr/bin/qgis  
Exec=/usr/bin/qgis %F`. I had tried the option `--noplugins` as mentioned in the related question mentioned above, but still no joy unfortunately.

Comment: Using `gdb`, I get `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
 0x00007fff54405b6f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libqgispython.so.2.14.3`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure your problem, you'll have to get the command the Application Launcher is calling or find someone else that can reproduce this error. However, the version of QGIS that Ubuntu has in the PPA is old. You can update with [Debian/Ubuntu repositories here](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html). I am on the updated version with Ubuntu 16.10 and I **can** launch 2.18 from a terminal.

Comment: thanks - yes, I'm aware of the PPAs and version that I'm using, but need 2.14 for a little longer. This is a fresh install of 14.04 and hadn't come across this issue before with 14.04 lts.

Comment: There is a QGIS 2.14.9 LTR version available, both with and without the ppa. Have you installed that?

Comment: Version 2.14 is installed using this ppa: ` http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main`, but if I use one of the debian/ubuntu repos, I get 2.18 but without orfeotoolbox available. Is that the case currently, or am I missing a ppa?